# What happened to my bounty?

Tags: bug, bounty

I put a 100 rep bounty on this question.

[When using Redux/Redux-Saga - should JWTs be set in the action creators/sagas?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/382355/when-using-redux-redux-saga-should-jwts-be-set-in-the-action-creators-sagas)

I have just received an email say it has expired - but I am unable to award it.

What has happened to it?

Answer (score 4):

Your bounty is gone since it's not awarded manually and there are no answers that are qualified to get auto-awarded.

From the FAQ, [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065):

> #### What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered? / What is automatic awarding?
>
> [Approximately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147576/bounty-not-awarded-after-the-end-of-the-grace-period/147577#147577) 24 hours after the end of the bounty period (once the grace period ends), if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be awarded automatically.
>
> If the author offered the bounty, and accepted an answer that was posted after the bounty was started, that answer is awarded the full bounty.
>
> Otherwise, all or half of the bounty is awarded to the highest-scored answer out of those which...
>
> - ...were posted *after* the bounty was started, and
> - ...have a score of at least 2 (at the time the automatic awarding takes place), and
> - ...were not written by the bounty starter.
>
> If the chosen answer was accepted by the question owner, it will receive the full bounty. Otherwise, it will receive half the bounty. If two eligible answers have the same score, the older answer is chosen.
>
> If no answer meets any of the above two criteria, the bounty is not awarded to any answer, and is *not* refunded to the bounty starter.

---

That said, [your bounty has expired since 13 Dec](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/382355/revisions). If you received an email about expired bounty today (16 Dec), then that might be bug. Otherwise, check the email header when it was sent, because [emails regarding bounty might be sent delayed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377006/2821954).